# TTTAttributedLabel detect multi links

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilabel, tttattritubedlabel

Is there a way to detect which link being pressed? I can open the "next" VC but I can't seem to detect which word. This is how I detect which words should be links:

```
NSArray *words = [cell.lblDescription.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    for (NSString *word in words) {
        if ([word hasPrefix:@"@"]) {
            at = [cell.lblDescription.text rangeOfString:word];
            [cell.lblDescription addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"action://at"] withRange:at];

        }else if ([word hasPrefix:@"#"]) {
            hash = [cell.lblDescription.text rangeOfString:word];
            [cell.lblDescription addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"action://hash"] withRange:hash];
        }
    }
```

Here is the method for the link link:

```
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url {

if ([[url scheme] hasPrefix:@"action"]) {
    if ([[url host] hasPrefix:@"hash"]) {
        /* load help screen */
        UIStoryboard  *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"viewTags" bundle:nil];
        OIOI_VC_ViewTags *viewController =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewTags"];
        viewController.str_word = ??????;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include the word in the URL. So, instead of using a URL of `action://at`, you could use `action://at?foo`; in your callback, you can get the `query` part of the URL and that will be the tapped word.